# Asymmetric hysteresis loop in Ising Model

Tags: ising-model

I am doing simulations using Monte Carlo of the 2 dimensional square lattice with periodic boundary conditions Ising model, and i obtain hysteresis loops, which are asymmetric. Meaning i obtain a different coercive field in negative and positive fields (like if the loop had been shifted in the external field axis)
I fix a temperature lower than the critical temperature, do 10^4 Monte Carlo steps with no external field, and then change linearly the external field from 0 to 0.1, back to -0.1, and to 0.1 again, with a step size of 0.0001, and doing for each value of the field 1000 Monte Carlo steps (in another simulation i did 100 steps).
I was expecting the loop to be symmetric, but it isn't. Any idea of the reason?

Thank you.